# A CONFUSE about the replacement proxy ip problem of the Scrapy framework

Tags: python, scrapy

I am currently trying to randomly try the proxy ip in the Scrapy framework.(I use Python3.6 and Scrapy version is 1.5.1,My project name is ip and the work name is ip_test), and I meet this confusing error:

`raise SchemeNotSupported("Unsupported scheme: %r" % (uri.scheme,))
twisted.web.error.SchemeNotSupported: Unsupported scheme: b''`
I dont know where I was wrong, and this is my middlewares.py

```
class IpDownloaderMiddleware(object):
PROXY = ["117.95.7.27:11170", "119.114.17.24:38715", "183.149.2.23:28970", "117.60.3.6:26965",
         "123.245.11.50:25550"]
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    proxy = random.choice(self.PROXY)
    request.meta["proxy"] = proxy
```

And this is my settings.py

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'ip.middlewares.IpDownloaderMiddleware': 100,}
```

thx!

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but your indentation on line 2 looks incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by the error message, Scrapy (or to be precise, Twisted) requires the proxy URL to include a scheme, instead of `<netloc>:<port>` only.

E.g. instead of setting `request.meta["proxy"] = '117.95.7.27:11170'`, you need `request.meta["proxy"] = 'http://117.95.7.27:11170'`